# SQL Server 6.5 jdbc (jdts) incompatibility

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, jdbc-odbc

I tried both jdts 1.2.2 and 1.2.5 (in DBVisualizer or IReport 4.5)to connect to a SQL Server 6.0.

the URL is

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/mydbname;instance=;TDS=4.2
```

But both version (1.2.2 and 1.2.5) give me error.

```
Please use TDS protocol version 7.0 or higher
```

If I change the URL to

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/mydbname;
```

It gives me this error.

```
Stream 0 attempting to read when no request has been sent
```

I actually just want to extract the data from SQL Server 6.0 into Excel format.

Could you anyone advise what I can do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it Sql Server 6.0 or 6.5? Your title and description don't match

Comment: It is SQL 6.0. Sorry for typo.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 6.0 is pretty old now so I suspect that might be part of your problem.

Microsoft provide a [jdbc driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx) for Sql Server which you could try instead of the **jtds** driver.

The oldest downloadable Microsoft jdbc driver is [version 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=2505) but even then Sql Server 2000 is the oldest version they support.